# How to disable cache in my custom contextual filter code?

Tags: 8, views, caching

I have created a custom module for authentication by using access_token. The authentication is working fine. So, I thought to create a custom contextual filter and use that as a filter by access token. Please find my code below.

```php
namespace Drupal\simple_auth\Plugin\views\argument_default;

use Drupal\views\Plugin\views\argument_default\ArgumentDefaultPluginBase;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Drupal\Core\Site\Settings;

/**
 * Default argument plugin for the current user's carts.
 *
 * @ViewsArgumentDefault(
 *   id = "uid_from_simple_auth_access_token",
 *   title = @Translation("User ID from Simple Auth Acess Token")
 * )
 */
class UserFilterByAccessToken extends ArgumentDefaultPluginBase implements CacheableDependencyInterface {

 /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getArgument() {
    return $this->extractUserIdFromAccessToken();
  }

  public function getCacheTags() {
    return [];
  }

  public function getCacheContexts(){
    return [];
  }

  public function getCacheMaxAge(){
    return 0;
  }

  /**
   * Extracts the user ID from the access token.
   */
  protected function extractUserIdFromAccessToken() {
    $request = \Drupal::request();
    $access_token = $request->headers->get('access-token');

    if (!$access_token) {
      return new JsonResponse([
          "error" => "Access token is required"
      ], 401);
    }

    $storedRefreshToken = hash('sha256', $access_token . Settings::get('simple_auth_access_secret_key'));

    $query = \Drupal::database()->select('simple_auth_access_tokens', 'sart');
    $query->fields('sart', ['uid', 'expiration_time']);
    $query->condition('sart.token', $storedRefreshToken);
    $result = $query->execute()->fetchAssoc();

    return $result['uid'];
  }
}
```

The above code have created my contextual filter in the view. But my exact issue here is,
for example,

```
  public function getArgument() {
    return 1;
  }
```

This filters the userid 1, when I check the view in browser (rest export view), and if I update the code like this

```
  public function getArgument() {
    return 2;
  }
```

I am getting the same result till clearing the cache. So I need to disable cache for this operation. I have tried many solutions but not getting what I have needed. I have tried adding cache tags and I cleared it using .module file, but it is not working.

Kindly help on this and if you need more info please reply.

Comment: More like add cache context.

Comment: Yes, add a user cache context. But first, refactor your code. The module is placing the authentication code in the wrong place, it needs to be in an authentication provider. See https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/authentication-api/create-a-custom-authentication-provider

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the function `cacheTags()`, I assume you mean `getCacheTags()`.

And you are returning the same cache tag for all your requests. A cache tag is data dependent and therefore must vary by data. The typical Drupal schema for individual cache tag strings is `entity_type:primary_key`. So if your data varies by user, you'd need something like

```
<?php

use \Drupal\Core\Cache\CacheableDependencyInterface;

class UserFilterByAccessToken extends ArgumentDefaultPluginBase implements CacheableDependencyInterface {
  public function getCacheTags() {
    return ['user:' . $this->extractUserIdFromAccessToken()];
  }
}
```

Comment: I think OP also needs `extends ArgumentDefaultPluginBase implements CacheableDependencyInterface {`.

Comment: When OP searches their project for that  exact string they will find examples in core.

Comment: @hudri, Thanks for your answer. I have updated my code please check my code above. Now here is the new scenario. **Check 1** - I am passing wrong access token -> I am getting empty result. **Check 2** - I am passing correct access token -> I am getting the required data which is good. **Check 3** - I am passing wrong token -> Here I am getting same data from **Check 2**, seems cache not clearing once the data is received.